# Integrate http trigger powershell azure Function app with app gateway

Tags: azure-functions, gateway

I have an http trigger azure function .I created an app gateway and routed it to function app and it seems working. But how can I route to http trigger function app?

Comment: You can refer to [Using a Route Template](https://marckean.com/2017/10/18/powershell-based-azure-functions/) ,  [HTTP triggered Azure Functions Default Routing](https://azurelessons.com/azure-function-http-trigger/#Azure_Function_HTTP_Trigger_Route),  and  [Routing In Azure Function](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/routing-in-azure-function/)

Answer (score 0):

We can update or override the route for our Http Triggered Azure function by modifying the route parameter in the function1.cs. By default the route parameter is assigned as null.

Suppose we want the route to send a request to our Azure function as localhost:7071/api/hello then we would need to simply assign the route parameter as hello.

```
public static class Function1  
    {  
        [FunctionName("Function1")]  
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(  
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = "Hello")] HttpRequest req,  
            ILogger log)  
        {  
            log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");  
  
            string name = req.Query["name"];  
  
            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();  
            dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);  
            name = name ?? data?.name;  
  
            string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)  
                ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."  
                : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";  
  
            return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);  
        }  
    }
```

Check the [Http Trigger Function](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/routing-in-azure-function/) for complete information about routing.